# Change Gatling protocols during scenario

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

I want to change the `Authorization` token during running Gatling scenario because I want to test with different users, this is my HTTP protocol:

```
val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("https://192.168.165.176:30479")
    .inferHtmlResources()
    .acceptHeader("application/json, text/plain, */*")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("IR")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0")
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer XXXX")
```

How can I change the `protocols` during running scenario in `setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(1) during (10 seconds))).protocols(httpProtocol)`
I want to define more than one `httpProtocol` and use them in one scenario

Comment: The `value` for `.header` is an `Expression[String]`, so you can use the [Gatling EL](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that's not possible. Protocols can be attached globally on the setUp, or on each scenario. Not on injection steps.

Comment: I think this is a case of [asking the wrong question](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal). The high level goal is to have different authorization headers for different users. OP erroneously think this is to be done by having multiple protocols.